# How to access token in response headers using Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angular, ionic-framework

I have the following code to authenticate a user using Ionic 2, angularjs and devise_token_auth, but if successful login, I receive the access-token  in the header of the response and not in json.

```
authenticate(user) {
        var creds = "email=" + user.name + "&password=" + user.password;
        var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

        return new Promise(resolve => {
            this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/auth/sign_in', creds, {headers: headers}).subscribe(data => {
                if(data.json().data){
                    this.storeUserCredentials("MY TOKEN IN THE HEADER");
                    resolve(true);
                }
                else
                    resolve(false);
            });
        });
    }
```

But I'm beginning to study AngularJS and ionic. I do not know to access the access-token in the header

Comment: Did you try to access `response.access_token`? This works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how , we can access a response header from $http response.

```
$http.post('/api').then(function(response) {
     //Accessing header
     console.log(response.headers()['access-token']);
});
```

Your code is a bit different. You can try this.

```
this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/auth/sign_in', creds, {headers: headers}).subscribe(data => {
            if(data.json().data){
                this.storeUserCredentials(data.json().headers()['access-token']);
                resolve(true);
            }
            else
                resolve(false);
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

`$scope.token=respone.headers('Authorization')` this line will return the token from the response.